# How to prevent useEffect from running on search input change due to updated dependency list in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added a search input to filter a list, but it causes the `useEffect` function (`validateUser`) to rerun every time I search within the input as if the list of elements being searched is updated by filter, here is the code:

I have list of elements as dependency of `useEffect`

```js
const { list } = useList()

useEffect(() => {  // gets called when I search in search input
    validateUser(currentUser, list)
}, [currenctUser, list])
```

Here is the logic how list is shown in JSX? how it is filtered? and how it is generated

```js
const getFilteredElements = (items) => {
  let parentMatched = false

  const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => {
    if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
      parentMatched = true
      return true
    }
    
    return false
  })

  return { filteredItems, parentMatched }
}


const createListBasedOnUser = (items, filterChildren = false) => {

  const { filteredItems, parentMatched } = getFilteredElements(items)

  const result = []

  for (const item of filterChildren ? items : filteredItems) {
    result.push({
      title: item.title,
    })
  }
}

const allLists = useMemo(() => {
  const elements = createListBasedOnUser(list, false)

  if (elements) {
    return [...elements]
  } else {
    return []
  }
}, [list, collapsed])


{* JSX *}
<ul>
  {allLists.map((array) => (
     <li key={array[0]}>
       {array.map((item) => (
         <span key={item}>{item}</span>
       ))}
     </li>
   ))}
</ul>
```

then here is the input with search value state:

```js
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('')

<input
  placeholder="Search value"
  value={searchValue}
  onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

As I search something in search input `validateUser` function within `useEffect` gets called, how do I prevent this?

Thank you

udpate: here is `useList` hook:

```
export default function useMenu() {
  let { data } = useQuery(GET_LIST)
  const list = _.cloneDeep(data)?.menuTree?.filter((i) => i.parentId === null) || []

  const otherMenus = data?.menuTree || []

  return { list, otherMenus }
}
```

Comment: when would you like to validate the user?

Comment: I check their role and based on that I show lists

Comment: The definition of the `useList` hook seems like it may be relevant here – if that is returning an unstable value then your effect will be re-run each time. Can you share that code?

Comment: Just added `useList` hook, please check the updated question

Comment: have you tried  modifying the dependency array from the `useEffect`? just to see which dependency (currentUser or list) is the one causing the effect to run again

Comment: run it with just the `currentUser` as a dependency then run it with just the `list` as the dependency

Comment: Just ran useEffect with `currentUser`, `useEffect` doesn't gets called when I search the input. However, as I add the `list` in dependency array, `useEffect` hook gets called and if I log `list` in useEffect, the list isn't updated when I search the input

Comment: It must be the `useList` hook then

Comment: I posted the useList hook, what could cause the issue?

Comment: The issue might be due to cloneDeep. Try removing that. Also you can save the data in the state in the custom hook useList

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that every time you’re updating `searchValue` the component is going to be re-rendered, therefore the custom hook `useList` will be called again and the `list` object reference is going to change too which is making the `useEffect` run again.

Move the `<input>` to a separate component and just pass the `searchValue` as a prop to the components that need it.

```
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('')

<input
  placeholder="Search value"
  value={searchValue}
  onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it is the same issue. I moved the input in another separate component and passed `searchValue` and `setSearchValue` as props, but I am still facing same issue.